# how to write string literal with new lines in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

How do you write a string literal with new line characters in Pharo 9? I tried the following but neither of them inserted the new line:

```
a := 'paragraph1\n\nparagraph2'.
a := 'paragraph1\\n\\nparagraph2'.
```

The only way I could see to do it was through concatenation like so:

```
a := 'paragraph' , 
     (String with: Character cr with: Character cr),
     'new paragraph' , 
     (String with: Character cr with: Character cr)
```

Is there a simpler (and shorter) way to do this?

Comment: Haven't dabbled in newer versions of Pharo, so take this with a grain of salt, but in Smalltalk, I believe the `Character cr` way is the way to do it. You could of course simplify it by creating a temporary variable if you're going to be doing it repetitively. You could (maybe even should) use a stream to build the string instead of concatenation. But the fact that there's no magic abbreviation that someone needs to be aware of, and that instead it's all done by sending messages between objects - that's very Smalltalk, and imho a good thing. (I can see how some would disagree, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just do your line:

```
multiLineString := 'paragraph1
paragraph2
paragraph3'.
```

Pharo (as any other Smalltalk AFAIK) has multiline strings, you do not need any special notation as in Python or others.

EDIT: Note that while **my** example will be a literal, yours will not (there will be 2 literals there, and the resulting string will not be a literal.
EDIT 2: There is also `String cr`.
EDIT 3: It can also be constructed with streams:

```
myMultiLineString := String streamContents: [ :stream |
    stream 
        nextPutAll: 'paragraph1'; cr;
        nextPutAll: 'paragraph2'; cr ]
```

Comment: In case you need a line end different from `String cr` use `String crlf` or `String lf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<n>` placeholder in your String and send it the `expandMacros` message - this will expand the placeholder to the platform line separator(s):

```
a := 'paragraph1<n>paragraph2' expandMacros.
```

`expandMacros` and its variants also accept placeholders for tabs, cr, lf and parameters. See the comment to `String>>expandMacrosWithArguments:` for more details.